# How to use sdpTransform in peerjs for high quality audio bitrate

Tags: javascript, webrtc, peerjs

1. I have implemented a video chat application using peerjs module
   everything is okay , but not getting a good audio quality .
2. How to use sdpTransform for setting the bitrate. can anyone please give a
   complete example of sdpTranform in PeerJS.

Comment: Have you found any solution? I also want to modify SDP, but don't know how to get SDP object from peerjs. I think, in your case you can use constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this,

```
let videoConstraints = {
     height: { min: 640, ideal: 1920, max: 1920 },
     width: { min: 400, ideal: 1080 },
     frameRate: { max: 30 }
   };

let audioConstraints = {
    channelCount: 1,
    sampleRate: <YOUR VALUE>,
    sampleSize: <YOUR VALUE>,
    volume: 1,
    latency: 0.003,
    echoCancellation: true,
    noiseSuppression: true,
    autoGainControl: true,
  };
  constraints = { audio: audioConstraints, video: videoConstraints };
```

Usage,

```
navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia(constraints)
...
```

Comment: how is reducing the sampleRate from the default 48khz to mere 16khz going to lead to more quality and not less?

Comment: @PhilippHancke sorry, that was my setup. Updated it.

Comment: echoCancellation: true,noiseSuppression: true,autoGainControl: true producing echo sounds for me

Comment: Also how can i add audio or video tracks in the middle of the session other than stream.getVideoTracks()[0].enable and stream.getAudioTracks()[0].enable